# Rails LoadError with openssl.so: undefined symbol: d2i_ECPKParameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

## rails --version

Rails 3.2.1

## ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]

## rpm -qa | grep openssl

openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5
openssl-devel-0.9.8e-20.el5
openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5

## uname -a

Linux 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Oct 17 11:57:14 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## rails new blog

```
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: d2i_ECPKParameters - /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:316:in `connection_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:368:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:203:in `fetch_http'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:231:in `fetch_path'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:265:in `load_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:231:in `block in list'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `list'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `block in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in `resolve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 11):

This problem arises when you don't install openssl prior to installing ruby. There are two fixes:

1. (Suggested fix) Install openssl and then recompile your version of ruby.  Assuming you are using rvm, you can solve this by doing: `rvm pkg install openssl` then `rvm remove 1.9.3` then `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr` which compiles ruby with openssl.
2. Modify your Gemfile to say `source "http://rubygems.org"` instead of `source "https://rubygems.org"`

Option 2 is quicker and easier, but more likely to cause problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

rvm pkg has been deprecated.

Instead try this if you are running the latest version of rvm (e.g. 1.21):

```
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall <ruby>
```

Where `<ruby>` is the version of ruby you are using. (e.g. rvm reinstall 1.9.3)

After you reinstall ruby check your .ruby-version file (replaces .rvmrc in latest version of rvm) and ensure it is set to the new version of ruby.

I ended up removing the gemset and recreating it before everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a different environment. Openssl tool was already installed by default. Ruby 1.9.2p320 was also installed by default at /usr/local and I was using rbenv installing other rubies at a custom location. Using Rails with the rbenv's ruby 1.8.7 and its openssl produced the undefined symbol: d2i_ECPKParameters error.

To fix it, I overrode my system default ruby and installed ruby 1.8.7 to /usr/local and installed its 
openssl via:

```
# after installing ruby 1.8.7 to /usr/local
# make sure the recent install ruby 1.8.7 is the default ruby
cd ruby-1.8.7-pXXX/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Then I created a symbolic link from the recent install openssl.so in /usr/local to my rbenv's ruby 
1.8.7's lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so

Rails started up with no more d2i_ECPKParameters error.