# Any rvm gem command results in openssl errors

Tags: ruby, linux, openssl, rubygems, rvm

Any time I try to run a gem command, my console spits out several SSL errors and fails to execute properly (for instance gem install xxx).

ssl errors:

```
brandon@ox:~/code/quotr$ gem install bundler
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

rvm info:

```
ruby-2.3.1:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux ox 3.13.0-101-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 22:08:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "debian/jessie_sid/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.27.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 day 1 hour 38 minutes 21 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/brandon/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.3.1p112"
    date:         "2016-04-26"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2016-04-26 revision 54768"
    full_version: "ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
    ruby:         "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/brandon/.rvm/bin:/home/brandon/gopath:/home/brandon/gopath/bin:/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/brandon/gopath:/home/brandon/gopath/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin/aws/bin:/home/brandon/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin/aws/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"
    IRBRC:        "/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

I even tried upgrading to the latest openssl version in order to fix this problem, but no dice.

```
brandon@ox:~$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016
```

My ruby correctly points to the right one and I have validated the path:

```
brandon@ox:~$ which ruby
/home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
brandon@ox:~$ cd /home/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
brandon@ox:~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin$ ls
erb  gem  irb  rake  rdoc  ri  ruby
brandon@ox:~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin$ ls -la
total 176
drwxrwxr-x 2 brandon brandon   4096 Nov 18 13:31 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 brandon brandon   4096 Nov 18 13:31 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon   4842 Nov 18 13:31 erb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon    546 Nov 18 13:31 gem
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon    190 Nov 18 13:31 irb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon    487 Nov 18 13:31 rake
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon    938 Nov 18 13:31 rdoc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon    188 Nov 18 13:31 ri
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brandon brandon 142504 Nov 18 13:31 ruby
```

I've been banging my head on this for the past week, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have successfully run a ruby stack on this OS for several months but had to re-install due to a hard drive failure and I cannot seem to get past this problem.

Is there a way to force rvm to use a different SSL version? It seems like it is pointing to an older version.

Comment: Also see [Building ruby with rbenv and ruby-build fails with undefined symbol: SSLv2_method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36286437), [undefined symbol: SSLv2_method when running bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12759518), [Rails LoadError with openssl.so: undefined symbol: d2i_ECPKParameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9732591), [Ubuntu and undefined symbol for SSLv2_method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8206546), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall openssl. You should to completely remove the old installation.Run this command:

```
apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
```

Then, download and compile:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0c.tar.gz
```

If it still doesn't work, try to reinstall rvm.

```
rvm implode
gem uninstall rvm
```

`rvm implode` will uninstall the `rvm/` directory and all the rubies built within it.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Last, reinstall ruby:

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I've done this already, thank you for the suggestion though.